# Storing JSON data into Realm db and back again

Tags: ios, json, swift

For some reason, I'm struggling in attempting to store a bit of JSON into my Realm db, and then retrieve it back as JSON again. I'm using SwiftyJSON for my JSON parsing, albeit an older version before they had rawData().

So I'm getting the JSON array as a string like this:

```
if let festivalNavArray = navDict["festivalInfo"]!.arrayValue {
  festMenu.string = festivalNavArray.description
}
```

and then storing into Realm. But when I try to read it back:

```
let newJson = JSON(object: festMenu.string)
if let array = newJson.arrayValue {
   println("array")
}
```

it doesn't get recognized as a JSON array anymore. Any help is greatly appreciated.

festMenu.string looks like this:

```
[[title: Food and Crafts, href: food-and-crafts, nav: [[title: Andy's Pancakes, href: andys-pancakes], [title: Sams Sushi, href: sams-sushi]]], [title: General Info, href: general-info, nav: [[title: About TOC Fest, href: about-toc-fest-2], [title: FAQs, href: faqs-2, nav: [[title: What To Bring/Not Bring, href: what-to-bringnot-bring], [title: RFID Wristband FAQ, href: rfid-wristband-faq], [title: Transportation FAQ, href: transportation-faq-2], [title: Ticketing FAQ, href: ticketing-faq-2], [title: Camping FAQ, href: camping-faq-2], [title: Concert FAQ, href: concert-faq-2], [title: General FAQ, href: general-faq-2], [title: Parking FAQ, href: parking-faq-2], [title: Accessibility, href: accessibility-2], [title: Directions, href: directions-2]]], [title: Getting There, href: getting-there], [title: Street Team Program, href: street-team-program-2], [title: Festival Map, href: festival-map-2], [title: Volunteering, href: volunteering], [title: Parking, href: parking-2]]], [title: News, href: news], [title: Ask Question, href: ask-question]]
```

Comment: That `festMenu.string` isn't valid JSON.